# Delphi 5.0 Open Interbase/FireBird connection via code

Tags: database, delphi, firebird, delphi-5, interbase

This is old stuff! Is related to delphi 5.0 and interbase 1.6.

I'm trying to open a DB connection via code. But this code is related to enabling the connection, all the components were added using delphi drag-drop User Interface: DataSource1, TForm1, DBGrid, DBNavigator etc..

```
procedure TDataModule2.DataModuleCreate(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
  database.DatabaseName:='C:\MyDatabase.GDB'; 
  database.Connected := true; 
  database.Open; 
  IBTransaction.Active := true; 

  myTable.Open; 
end;
```

I have a TForm with DBGrid and DBNavigator component. I also have a TIBQuery (that DataSource1 is associated to) with this code on the SQLStrings:

```
SELECT * FROM NEW_TABLE
```

On the Form I have this code to enable DBNavigator and DBGrid to show the DB Values. The DB is very simple is just a table: NEW_TABLE with a NEW_VALUE of VARCHAR type

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
  DataSource1.DataSet.Open;
  // This will call the query associated to this DataSource1 the tibQuery1 to call
  // SELECT * FROM NEW_TABLE, but the message below appears: IBClientError...
end;
```

The message appears:
IBClientError with message 'Database not assigned'

OBS1: If I connect the components by hand on delphi user interface, the connection with the DB is established.

Comment: Have you created an instance of TDataModule2?

Comment: yes, I'll change the description, The TDataModule2 is desined not by source but with the delphi UserInterface, all the components were put with the delphi drag-drop ui: DataSource1, TForm1, DBGrid, DBNavigator etc..

Comment: I changed the code, I called DataSource1.DataSet.Open; the error appears IBClientError with message 'Database not assigned'

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign the [`Database`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/IBCustomDataSet.TIBCustomDataSet.Database) property of your query, something like:

```
IBQuery1.Database := MyDatabase;
```

Comment: It is set to: DataModule2.database, Database
I think it is somenthing very specific like BDE alias something like that... I'm look for it.

Comment: I believe that if it was set you would not get the error, please check again. Also check Transaction, BTW.

Comment: Are you getting the same error if you open the query at design time (by assigning true to the Active property)?  You should double check the database assignment (maybe it is lost at runtime) because the only place and situation where a error with this message is raised is in TIBCustomDataSet.ActivateConnection if the Database property is nil.